# Is it possible to create IF statement using AND, OR or NOT only?

Tags: if-statement, operators

I have a situation where I need to evaluate certain variables but I do not have access to IF ... ELSE because of legacy issues.

Is it possible to create IF evaluations using just `&`,`|` and `!` and basic math.

```
var1 = 1;
var2 = 0;
var3 = 1;
```

Psuedo example I am trying to achieve using and,or and not. No else required.

```
assert[ if (var1 == 1) then { var2 == 1 OR var3 ==1 } ] is true or false
```

also

```
assert [ if ( var1 = 0 ) then { var2 == 0 AND var3 == 0 ) ] is true or false
```

I have been trying various combinations but I cant work out how to negate a true based on a false outcome, if that makes sense. I dont need else, just IF the first var1 is set to 1 then the either other tow need to be 1.

Because these are numbers I am sure I need to do some kind of calculation but cant really find how IF works on a low level.

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: I don't quite understand what the requirements are. How would you write it if you did have if phrases available? `if( var1 == 1 ) { ??? }`

Comment: Programmin language is irrelevant. I did not specify one. I am asking how to create a conditional using logical operators. You see the tags? All programming languages evaluete and or or in the same ways dope. I `cant use IF`

Comment: switch ;) (i know you would bang me)

Comment: cant use switch also

Comment: You saying you cant use if so can you use ternary?

Comment: So what you actually want is to evaluate `(var1 == 1 AND (var2 == 1 OR var3 == 1)) OR (var1 == 0 AND var2 == 0 AND var3 == 0))`

Comment: I can only use what I wrote in the question. basic math, and, or, not

Comment: Did I use something else then?

Comment: No sorry Juhana, almas asked if i can use ternary. I think your comment solves what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In languages with short-circuiting evaluation of logical AND and OR, you can use them to implement conditional control flow, no `if` statements necessary.  That doesn't seem to be what you are doing.

You appear to want to test implications.  For example,

```
var1 => var2 OR var3
```

If your language supports [implication testing directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242794%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), you're done.  Otherwise I'll show you how to implement using the standard boolean operators.

These can be tested by noting that if the left-hand side isn't met, the implication is automatically satisfied.

```
NOT var1 => holds
```

Also, if the right-hand side is met, the implication is also satisfied

```
var2 OR var3 => holds
```

Putting it together:

```
holds := (NOT var1) OR var2 OR var3
```

The second implication reduces to

```
holds2 := var1 OR ((NOT var2) AND (NOT var3))
```

Applying DeMorgan gives

```
holds2 := var1 OR NOT (var2 OR var3)
```

Putting them together:

```
both_hold := holds AND holds2
```

and simplifying

```
both_hold := ((NOT var1) OR var2 OR var3) AND (var1 OR NOT (var2 OR var3))
```

And recognizing a pattern

```
both_hold := var1 XNOR (var2 OR var3)
```

(In C-like languages, XNOR can be expressed as `==` on boolean variables)

However, none of this matches your plain language description

> just IF the first var1 is set to 1 then the either other tow need to be 1

That sounds more like

```
text_holds := (var1 XNOR var2) AND (var2 XNOR var3)
```

Comment: XNOR looks looks good but I think I will have to fully expand that into the base Exclusive Not OR evaluation as I doubt XOR even works.

Comment: @ppumkin: What language?

Comment: Its not a language, it just a thing that was made in the "cold war" but for some reason costs a crap of load of money to redo...

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((var1 and (var2 or var3)) or (!var1 and (!var2 and !var3)))
```

OK didn't understand the question properly. To get the above without an IF, can you just split out the logic like this? I am assuming it does not need to be a single statement.

```
varA = (var1 and (var2 or var3))
varB = (!var1 and (!var2 and !var3))
result = varA or VarB
```

Comment: Wouldnt that be `(var1 and (var2 or var3)) OR (!var1 and (!var2 and !var3))` ?